# XPages - Using Ampersand in URL query string

Tags: cgi, query-string, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a XPage which is passing information to another XPage in the form of a URL parameter (this is important due to SEO). I am able to use: `java.net.URLEncoder.encode` to encode the URL and then I can have ampersand in my parameter value and I am able to use just `param.get()` to get the values without decoding them. This works fine, but when I combine this with server side substitution it doesn't work as expected, it reverts the ampersand back to a normal ampersand rather than %26. Any ideas would be really appreciated here? Server side substitution is important due to SEO as well.

**Update:**

This is the URL before the submission as displayed in the address-bar (if we assume my category is Fruit & Vegetables):

```
/product-byCategory/Fruit+%26+Vegetables
```

The server side substitution rule is:

```
- /product-byCategory/*
- /mywebsite.nsf/xspProductByCat.xsp?cat=*
```

The query string value is:

```
cat=Fruit+&+Vegetables
```

What's interesting is that if I type this URL in the address-bar, I get the correct query string:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/mywebsite.nsf/xspProductByCat.xsp?cat=Fruit+%26+Vegetables
```

Comment: You could do redirects in you xpages upon load instead of using substitutions.

Comment: Thanks Thomas - but I am not sure if search engines will be too happy about this.

Comment: Do you have an example of a URL before/after substitution?

Comment: Tommy, I have updated the question with this information - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem, but I searched (and found) a different solution. I don't need substitution, I don't use a QueryString, and Google apparently doesn't mind.

I use this type of URL:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/mywebsite.nsf/xspProductByCat.xsp/Fruit+%26+Vegetable
```

Instead of the QueryString, I get the extended information through

```
    var name= facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestPathInfo();
```

The pages of a website that was created this way are correctly indexed by Google and Bing. We're not entirely satisfied about the page ranks but that's a different topic.

Here are the [website](http://www.the-academy.nl) and a example of an [extended URL](http://www.the-academy.nl/TA.nsf/Page.xsp/Training/MS10953--HTML5-Programming)

Comment: Many thanks D.Bugger - that's a very interesting solution. For the time being for this one specific problem we converted "Fruit & Vegetables" to "Fruit and Vegetables" in the URL and then when it's displayed, I used @Replacesubstring to replace and with & and the customer is happy with that solution for now.

Comment: I really like your solution, but the customer wants the URL to look natural rather than have the notes db path. Just tried &amp; and that doesn't work either. I am happy with this solution where I replace " and " with " & " in the UI (I look for " and " including spaces in order to make sure part of the word is not replaced).

Comment: I might try combining your solution with server side substitution - I presume the values can be anything if we are using a "/" as a separator as per your suggestion.